# Is there a way to get the re-connect event on the WebSocketSubject?

Tags: websocket, rxjs

I try to use the WebSocketSubject, and implement re-connection in case the connection dies. I try to use the provided hooks (openObserver, closeObserver etc.). When I close my network connection the observers are not called, and no log output in the retryWhen.

My code is something like this:

```
let open
const openObservable = rx.Observable.create(observer => open = observer)
openObservable.subscribe((m: OpenEvent) => console.error('open observer'))

let close
const closeObservable = rx.Observable.create(observer => close = observer)
closeObservable.subscribe((m: OpenEvent) => console.error('close observer', m))

let closing
const closingObservable = rx.Observable.create(observer => closing = observer)
closingObservable.subscribe((m: OpenEvent) => console.error('closing observer', m))

this.ws$ = rx.Observable.webSocket({
  url: 'ws://example.com/ws,
  WebSocketCtor: WebSocket,
  openObserver: open,
  closeObserver: close,
  closingObserver: closing,
})
  .retryWhen(errors => {
    logger.warn('Connection error!')

    return errors.delayWhen(() => rx.Observable.timer(Math.pow(2, 1)))
  })
 .subscribe(m => doStuff(m))
```

My question:

- Are the observers supposed to work, and be used for this use case?
- Is my approach correct?

Environment:

- Linux
- NodeJS 9
- WebSocket (ws library v5)
- rxjs 5